# How to approach teaching Jewish ethics morality for a 12 year old?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, product-recommendation, mussar-ethics, chinuch-education

How to describe and teach Jewish ethics/morality to 12 year old?

Seeking topic lists, curricula, books, etc. on the topic of Jewish ethics/morality appropriate for a 12 year old.  These might be case studies or more general principles.

Comment: Does "by example" count?

Comment: @DoubleAA Yes, certainly.  But by example can be a slow, haphazard process.  Other ideas/suggestions?

Comment: לא יגעת ומצאת, אל תאמין

Comment: אורחות צדיקים..

Comment: @kouty OK, but it seems a bit heavy for a 12 yer old: https://www.sefaria.org/Orchot_Tzadikim.1?lang=bi   Any part in particular you were thinking of?

Comment: @DoubleAA Megila 6b?

Comment: @yehuda that's where that quote is from... There are no shortcuts in life if you want real quality results.

Comment: "by example can be a slow, haphazard process" - Is there a specific reason as to why you need to have quick results? the child is 12, meaning, that, hopefully, s/he has a long life ahead to learn and adjust to things. It takes a village to raise a child properly. You and a properly formed village will be the best method. Seriously, regardless of what 100 books teach the child, it can be all destroyed in a few minutes by exposure to the wrong examples and people.

Answer (score 4):

[Syllabus Morasha](https://www.morashasyllabus.com/aboutus.htm) has a very nice collection of educational resources which works well with older children (I tried it with mine). Amongst their [many topics](http://www.morashasyllabus.com/Syllabus.htm), they have a number related to ethics and morality, e.g.,

- [Ethics](https://www.morashasyllabus.com/Syllabus.htm#Ethics)
- [Between people](https://www.morashasyllabus.com/Syllabus.htm#Ben)
- [Tsedaka](https://www.morashasyllabus.com/Syllabus.htm#Possessions)
- [Ecology and the environment](https://www.morashasyllabus.com/Syllabus.htm#Ecology)

Alternatively, in terms of books, you could use R Joseph Telushkin

- [The Book of Jewish Values: A Day-by-Day Guide to Ethical Living](http://a.co/5ufV5ys)
- [A Code of Jewish Ethics: Volume 1: You Shall Be Holy](http://a.co/7pmAH9v)
- [A Code of Jewish Ethics, Volume 2: Love Your Neighbor as Yourself](http://a.co/3ZmfQpJ)

Answer (score 1):

Beyond [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/92972/11501) other excellent answer, I would heavily recommend learning Pirkei Avos. This is suitable for all ages, and is really an excellent basis. Note that there is also a plethora of commentaries on it, some of which will be useful whilst others will be more  advanced.

Answer (score 0):

I was also thinking of *Pirkei Avot*, as @Orangelsandlemons suggested. In particular, an adage in there says that one should make for himself a *rav* and *acquire* a friend.

I won't delve into what the differences are and why you need both, as you can find these answers among various commentaries. However, you absolutely need both if you will be successful. You can find a rav for him. But, ultimately, your child has to be the one to acquire the friend. You and others can suggest, but the friendship has to be mutually compatible and effective.

I would also recommend learning *Mishlei* as it is filled with wisdom written by the wisest person. What better mentor than King Solomon? I will admit that much of Mishlei is somewhat hard to understand, but there is loads of commentary as well as several good English translations around.

Comment: Interesting that in your comment to the question you suggest that people are more important than books, and here you recommend following Pirkei Avot to acquire a friend, and Rashi's first explanation is that "friend" means books.